# How to calculate durarion from date time entry dates?

Tags: tableau-api

I have 4500000 rows of data of workers processing units which is the following format: ***entry date in DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS format and quantity***

This is the raw data for one worker:

```
ENTRY_DATE          QUANTITY
08.07.2018 19:09    1
08.07.2018 19:09    1
08.07.2018 19:09    1
08.07.2018 19:09    1
08.07.2018 19:09    2
08.07.2018 19:09    4
08.07.2018 19:09    8
08.07.2018 19:09    11
08.07.2018 19:10    1
08.07.2018 19:10    1
08.07.2018 19:10    1
08.07.2018 19:10    2
08.07.2018 19:10    3
08.07.2018 19:10    3
08.07.2018 19:10    4
08.07.2018 19:10    8
08.07.2018 19:10    8
08.07.2018 19:10    2
08.07.2018 19:10    7
08.07.2018 19:10    1
```

Is it possible to get of how long worker worked from this data? I know the raw data example is bad since it shows only one minute. But it goes on for whole day and multiple days etc.

Worker names are specified in separate column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tableau, according to the data that is given, you can **Create Calculated Field** with the expression **{ FIXED [Name],DATE([Entrydate]): DATEDIFF('minute',MIN([Entrydate]),MAX([Entrydate])) }** (This will return the difference in Minutes. You can change it to **hour,day, etc**) and drag **WorkerName** dimension and the new calculated field in the Rows section. Then change the calculated field to Discrete in Rows section.

Comment: Hey, sorry for late reply. I  tried this and it doesn't work. It shows that worker worked for 33 hours per day on average which doesn't make sense... [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/oQAMU5b.png)    I use DATEDIFF('hour',MIN([ENTRY_DATE]),MAX([ENTRY_DATE]))

Comment: I have edited the **expression** in answer. I'm assuming that the time difference you want is between first entry time and last entry time of each day for each worker.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to include calculation that will exclude gaps? Now it shows that one "worker" (station) worked for 23 hours but it is impossible since the max value should be 20 (20 hours is how long the shift is). If I include breaks it should be 18 hours max. example at 4 oclock followed by 18 oclock: https://i.imgur.com/8mPy3vB.png

Comment: If there is any identification for the break time you can use it to deduct from new calculated value.